# Use Javascript to create dynamic input id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use javascript to create `<input/>` tags with a dynamic `id` (`name` attribute will be the same) depending on the order in which they appear.

I have the first `<input/>` tag in plain html and a div that should append a new `<input/>` with an incremented id when clicked:

```
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" />
<div class="add_new" onClick="add_new_input()">+</div>
```

Now, the javascript needs to count the amount of `<input/>`s currently being displayed (count) and use that amount to generate a dynamic `id` (count+1).

Therefore if the `<div class="add_new"><..` is clicked twice, the output should be as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" />
<input type="text" name="2" id="2" />
<input type="text" name="3" id="3" />
```

If I append the new `<input/>` tag in my form using jquery's `append()`, would this add to the previously appended `<input/>`s? Or would I need to append one `<input/>`, then two, then three, etc?

Also, how can I use javascript to count the amount of `<input/>`s currently being displayed?

Comment: you can use `$(':input:text').size()` to count the text input control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had used script which is fit in your requirement .

**Html:**

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
    <label for="p_scnts">
        <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
    </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

**Javascript :-**

```
  $(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
    });
  });
```

<kbd>[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Try like

```
function add_new_input() {
   var last_id = $('input[type="text"]:last').attr('id');
   last_id++;
   $('input[type="text"]:last').append('<input type="text" name="'+last_id+' id="'+last_id+'">');
}
```

Comment: Ok, so javascript would remember the last appended `<input/>` after every click?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function add_new_input(){
   var lastControlId = $('input:text:last').attr('id');
   if(!lastControlId){
    lastControlId = parseInt(lastControlId,10) + 1;
    $('#containerDiv').append('<input type="text" name="'+ lastControlId +' id="'+ lastControlId +'">');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g3Be3/2/)

```
jQuery('#select').change(function () {
var val = jQuery(this).val();
var innerhtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
    innerhtml += "<input type='text' id='" + (i + 1) + "' name='" + (i + 1) + "'size=50>   </br>";
}
jQuery('#textbox_div').html(innerhtml);
});
```

Comment: Nice solution! Not precisely what I was looking for but may use this elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div>Hello world mggp</div>
<div id="li">
    
</div>
<button type="button" onclick=add() class="btn btn-light">+addtodo</button>
<script>
var i =1;
function add() {

document.getElementById('li').innerHTML+=`<div 
id="li${i}">added</div>`;
i++

 }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please describe your code and say somethings about your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'item-' + index);
});
```

This should alter all inputs with id of "item-[index number]".

But you should throw in .class identification to selector so this doesn't apply to all.

Answer (score 0):

using plain javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
    var x=1;
    function add_new_input(){
        x++;
        var input=document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("id",x);
        input.setAttribute("type","text");

        document.getElementById("holder").appendChild(input);

    }
</script>
```

html is below

```
<div id="holder">
<input type="text" name="1" id="1" />
</div>
<div class="add_new" onClick="add_new_input()" >+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 1;


function add_fields() {

    index++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('room_fileds')
    var divtest = document.createElement("tr");
    divtest.innerHTML = ("<tr><td class='slno'>" + index + "</td><td><input type='text'></td><td><button class='remove_button' onclick='myfn()'>remove</button></td></tr>");
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
     $(".slno").each(function(index, element) {
            $(element).text(index + 1);

       });

}

function myfn() {
        $(".remove_button").parents('tr').first().remove();
        $(".slno").each(function(index, element) {
            $(element).text(index + 1);

        });
}
```

Comment: <button onclick="add_fields()">add input </button>
  <table id="room_fileds">
     <tr>
       
       </tr>
</table>