# How to call ajax when id is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two input field with add more button. If the user clicks on "Add" button that will display two more input type text with different id name.

I am using the keyup function on the second input field. If the user enters any value then it will call my ajax function.

Now my issue is, How to call ajax when it is dynamic? I mean How to send the x value to the ajax? I jusr want to know about

```
$("#total_p_price").keyup(function (){));
```

how to call from dynamic?

Check When the First time I enter the number=2 and total_p_price=10 and it calculates it and display single_price=5.

[image]

which is right. now I click on Add button. this time number=4 and total_p_price=100 and it's calculate it and display single_price=50. It's also correct but it's updated the first single_price field as well.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="add_row">
  <input type="text" name="" id="number">
  <input type="text" name="" id="total_p_price">
  <input type="text" name="" id="single_price">
  <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        $(wrapper).append('<div class="custom_fields"><input type="text" name="" id="number' + x '"><input type="text" name="" id="total_p_price' + x '"><input type="text" name="" id="single_price' + x '"> <div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div>');
      }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
      e.preventDefault();
      //$(this).parent('custom_fields').remove();
      $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();

      x--;
    })
    $("body").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
      //$('input[id^=single_price]').prop('disabled', true);
      var total_p_price = $(this).val();
      var qty_number = $('input[id^=number]').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/Customer_control/calculate_total_p_price",
        data: {
          total_p_price: total_p_price,
          qty_number: qty_number
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          //alert(html);
          $('input[id^=single_price]').val(html);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Observer, Sorry, I haven't understood this. can you explain more?

Comment: You should bind the events before you append the control then you wont have issues.

Comment: @Marie, any more help in this issue?

Comment: You would have to construct the custom_fields elements separately to bind the event to one of them as far as I know. Another option is to use a class on the inputs and a namespace and just toggle the event off then back on. For example `$(".the_class").off("keyup.someRandomNamespace").on("keyup.someRandomNamespace", function () { ... }). This would be a little slower but would ensure you dont double-bind your events and it should be pretty easy to implement.

Comment: @Marie, I solved this issue, Now I am getting some calculation issue. Please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664720/dynamic-input-field-values-are-not-calculating-the-with-the-right-value   . Can you help me out in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about your question, you need to use event delegation. Something like

```
$(".add_row").on("keyup","#total_p_price", function (){
    var  total_p_price= $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type  : "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "/Customer_control/calculate_total_p_price",
        data: {total_p_price: total_p_price},
        cache : false,
        success: function(html) {
            console.log(html);

        }
     });
});
```

You need to ensure the add_row element is a static element in your HTML.

Comment: This is not my issue, It will work only for single input with a single id, I have multiple inputs with multiple id

Comment: No, because it's not calling keyup function when entering the value in the text field

Comment: From your updated question, it seems you need to assign dynamic ids to each row of text boxes that your create. You can refer this for implementing such functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994281/use-javascript-to-create-dynamic-input-id

Comment: I am getting the issue in       var qty_number = $('input[id^=number]').val(); and $('input[id^=single_price]').val(html); because when I am adding the dynamic field and adding the total amount then it's chamging the previous value

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery wild card selector  like `input[id^=total_p_price]` and delegate the event from the body

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      $(wrapper).append('<div class="custom_fields"><input type="text" name="" class="form_control"><input type="text" class="form_control" id="total_p_price' + x + '" name="" /> <div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).parent('custom_fields').remove();
    $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();

    x--;
  })
  $("body").on('keyup', 'input[id^=total_p_price]', function() {
    var total_p_price = $(this).val();
    console.log(total_p_price);
    //ajax here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_row">
  <input type="text" name="" class="form_control">
  <input type="text" name="" id="total_p_price">
  <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I aaded alert($total_p_price) but I am not getting the alert.

Comment: I think the correct solution is to bind the events when you create the dynamic elements.

Comment: @Marie, You mean to say I have to use "bind" instated of "on"?

Comment: @brk, Is it a correct <input type="text" class="form_control" id="total_p_price'+ x +'" name="" > my Id is id="total_p_price'+ x +'" but it;s not sending the value

Comment: @user9437856 I meant that I think you should use `on` immediately before/after appending the element. You could even create the element, assign it to a variable, on the keyup, and then append the element.

Comment: @brk, I updated my HTML and AJAX code. Please check it. Your code is working but I am getting the functionality issue as well now. For example, I enter number and total_p_price and that calculate it and display in the single_price field. It's working first time. If I click "add more" then it's taking the first number value and its response is also displaying in both fields.

Comment: Check When First time I am enter the number=2 and total_p_price=10 and it's calculate it and display single_price=5 https://prnt.sc/kdmf0n. which is right.  now I click on Add button. this time number=4 and total_p_price=100 and it's calulate it and display single_price=50. It's also correct but it's updated the first on single_price https://prnt.sc/kdmf8s

Comment: @brk, Any more help in this?

Answer (score -1):

Better use `className` instead of `id` for multiple selector .Because id mainly used for individual single element Selector.  And also you are creating the input as dynamic. So you could use [`on()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) function of jquery

**Note**

> click event binded before the element append. So you could use [`on()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) function of jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment

      $(wrapper).append('<div class="custom_fields"><input type="text" name="" class="form_control"><input type="text" class="form_control total_p_price" id="total_p_price' + x + '" name="" /> <div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).parent('custom_fields').remove();
    $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();

    x--;
  })

});
$(document).on('keyup', '.total_p_price', function() {
  var total_p_price = $(this).val();
  //ajax goes here
  console.log(total_p_price)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add_row">
  <input type="text" name="" class="form_control">
  <input type="text" name="" id="total_p_price">
  <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Prasanth, There is no issue with dynamic field, I am getting the dynamic field when clicking on add button. My issue is, I have to call ajax after entering the value in the text box.

Comment: ya of course. click event binded before the element append. Thats why i was say use with on().Read the usage of on(). its helpfull to solve your issue.

Comment: as a down voter .please share what's wrong with my answer?