# How to obtain id for a list of rows when user clicks on a Trash Can?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am using C#, JavaScript, HTML, Backbone!
I have a list of Groups on HTML page where each row has a Trash Can and pencil icon in order to delete/edit the Group/row. The pencil/Edit works fine however, the Trash Can/Delete does not work.  Here is a sample of HTML:

```
  <%
    _.each(Groups, function(Group){ %>
    <td><%=Grp.Nm%></td>
    <td>
        <div class="row ">
           <div class="col-sm-10 text-right font-m pl-3">
               <span>
                   <a id="edit-1"
                      [href="<%= Group.EditLink %>"][1]
                      class="icon"
                      data-toggle="tooltip"
                      title="Edit Group">
                      <span class="icon-edit"></span>
                   </a>
               </span>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-2 font-m pl-3">
               <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-group">
                   <a id="OK"
                      class="icon"
                      data-toggle="tooltip"
                      title="Delete Group">
                      <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                   </a>
                </span>
           </div>
      </div>
      </td>
   <%})%>
```

Here is a sample of the C# code that list the rows:

```
base.Model.Groups.Add( new Group {
    Name = thTet,
        DeleteLink = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",  
        Common.HostMapping.Factory.NavigationMap.DeleteGroup(), 
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode("?groupId="), theValue) });
```

When the User clicks the Trash Can a modal pops up for the User to Confirm the delete.  This is where I cannot get the id of the row with the modal popping up. So without the id I cannot delete the row.

NOTE: The Listener in the View.js is triggering the correct method but there is no id.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In DOM all the element id is same "OK" ,  Read more here to create dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994281/use-javascript-to-create-dynamic-input-id